# Php mail() is not working but sendmail is.

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, sendmail

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running with RH/Linux. My problem is php mail() function which is not working although I can send mail with sendmail from command line.

I run this command. `# telnet localhost 25`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
XXXXX
```

My php.ini setting is

```
 mail function]
 SMTP = localhost
 smtp_port = 25
 sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
 mail.add_x_header = On
```

I can't fingure out whats wrong. I am not getting any php mail error. I don't get any email as well. What could the problem be?

Comment: `SMTP` and `smtp_port` are for Windows only thus remove them from your configuration. What parameters are you using with `sendmail` when sending manually?

Comment: Thanks this is the way I send from sendmail

sendmail mymail@gmail.com
I am testing
Bye!
.

Comment: I assume `/usr/bin/sendmail` does exist? Try and run the command `locate sendmail` to see where it sits..

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sos/plugins/sendmail.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sos/plugins/sendmail.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sos/plugins/sendmail.pyo
/usr/sbin/sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
/usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
/usr/share/doc/sendmail-8.14.4

Answer (score 4):

Sending mail on EC2 is notoriously difficult.  Most of the EC2 IP addresses are in spamming blacklists.  This, combined with PHP `mail()`'s terrible error reporting results in a pretty horrible experience.

You'll want to use [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) in combination with EC2.  They recently added an [SMTP service](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SMTP.html), meaning you can use any standards-compliant PHP mailing library to send mails.

I personally recommend [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) for this task.